# User registration page edit

Tags: users

I want to add some div's and hrefs to user registration form. any ideas? I'm using ajax login/register module to get user login/register form in ajax windows. and i have no idea how to add some divs and hrefs to register form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Drupal 7.

Using [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) and a custom module you can achieve it. Like below,

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['links'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => l('some links','http://www.example.com'),           
  );
  $form['additional_markup'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#markup' => '<div></div>',          
  );
}
```

Comment: thx. as i understand i should paste it in template.php?

Comment: yes, it would also work in template.php file.

Answer (score 1):

In other hand you can use Display Suite. It provide you great solution to customize things.  With it you can create new registration fields  the way you want it and then you can customize de display...

Comment: Is it possible to manage user/register page form by Display Suite?

Comment: Yes, it's possible

Comment: Follow the screencasts of this guy about display suite and you will master it. The link http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rSgd91tZSEc

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much! I was looking for this ability so much time!